# Was a misplaced decimal point responsible for the popular belief that spinach has a lot of iron?

Tags: nutrition, history-of-science, iron, spinach

Daniel Engber writes in [Who Will Debunk The Debunkers?](https://fivethirtyeight.com/features/who-will-debunk-the-debunkers):

> Popeye loved his leafy greens and used them to obtain his super strength, Arbesman’s book explained, because the cartoon’s creators knew that spinach has a lot of iron. Indeed, the character would be a major evangelist for spinach in the 1930s, and it’s said he helped increase the green’s consumption in the U.S. by one-third. But this “fact” about the iron content of spinach was already on the verge of being obsolete, Arbesman said: In 1937, scientists realized that the original measurement of the iron in 100 grams of spinach — 35 milligrams — was off by a factor of 10. That’s because a German chemist named Erich von Wolff had misplaced a decimal point in his notebook back in 1870, and the goof persisted in the literature for more than half a century.
>
> [...]
>
> All these tellings and retellings miss one important fact: The story of the spinach myth is itself apocryphal. It’s true that spinach isn’t really all that useful as a source of iron, and it’s true that people used to think it was. But all the rest is false: No one moved a decimal point in 1870; no mistake in data entry spurred Popeye to devote himself to spinach; no misguided rules of eating were implanted by the sailor strip.

Is it true that the story that Arbesman and other tell about how the misplacement of a decimal point by Erich von Wolff lead to a popular misconception about the iron content of spinach is false?

Comment: As far as I remember it was no displacement of a comma but using the dry mass of the spinach instead of the wet mass.

Comment: http://historiesofecology.blogspot.de/2015/08/on-spinach-iron-wolff-1880.html has some very interesting details.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Was a misplaced decimal point responsible for the popular belief that spinach has a lot of iron?

**No.**

**It was an *interpretation* error of von Wolff's findings, of about a factor of ten.**

What happened was that von Wolff (*correctly*) measured the iron content of **dried** spinach, but his numbers were interpreted as the iron content of **fresh** spinach (which happens to be less by about a factor of ten).

[SPINACH, IRON and POPEYE: Ironic lessons from biochemistry and history on the importance of healthy eating, healthy scepticism and adequate citations](http://www.internetjournalofcriminology.com/Sutton_Spinach_Iron_and_Popeye_March_2010.pdf) has the whole story, and contains lots of links to further sources on how the myth began and was perpetuated.

Funny sidenote: Our metabolism cannot even *digest* the iron...

Comment: source for your funny sidenote? xd

Comment: @Mindwin: Either the linked source, the German WP page on spinach, or one of the sources linked from there. I didn't actually read much if anything about spinach before today. ;-) I hope that is precise enough for a coment-answer. ;-)

Comment: @Mindwin: Tracked it. It's just a sidenote (there's that word again...) in [this](http://www.spiegel.de/wissenschaft/mensch/hartnaeckige-irrtuemer-mythen-an-die-selbst-mediziner-glauben-a-525056.html) article (German language). Further digging hinted at a high content of oxalic acid inhibiting absorption of the iron into the body.

Comment: Ok, if you don't want to be linked, you won't. I understand. Lets delete this conversation thread from 3 mins ago since it server its purpose. Posting Q now.

Comment: [Can humans digest the iron present in spinach?](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/34220)